# In Android Navigation Architecture, how can I call one of destination fragments' methods from the host (activity)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I use Navigation Architecture in my project and I have some fragments as destinations. Its host is my MainActivity. Now I want to call one of my destinations' methods from the host (MainActivity). What should I do?

Comment: Hello Ehsan, welcome to SO! The short answer is: *don't*. Don't attempt to call methods directly on a Fragment, fragments are very picky classes and rely on a number of external factors to operate (at the very least, they are tied to a lifecycle so you don't know what state they may be in). Instead, *separate* the logic you need to perform into separate classes and interfaces... call those, have those talk to your fragments.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear @MartinMarconcini. I will try. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the navController and then call the destination fragment by action I'd or destination I'd as defined in your navigationgraph.xml

Refer Android doc for navigating to destination section:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#java

//Sample code

Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.viewTransactionsAction);

Comment: better answer than mine, i am deleting mine in favor of this

Comment: thanks dear Ashok. But I don't want to move between two destinations. I have one method inside one of my destinations (fragment) and I want to call it from the host (my MainActivity)

Comment: Did you find the answer to it? How do you get an instance of fragment to call its method?